# In Docker.DotNet how do you build an image by specifying the directory of the Dockerfile?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I am trying to build an image and start a container, for the purposes of integration testing, in a C# xunit test. I currently have the code below, but can't find away to specify the path to the docker file. The client does have `Images.BuildImageFromDockerfileAsync` but that deals with unpacking TAR files.

```
        using(var client = new DockerClientConfiguration(
            new Uri(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) 
                ? "npipe://./pipe/docker_engine"
                : "unix:/var/run/docker.sock")).CreateClient())
        {
            await client
                .Images
                .CreateImageAsync(
                    new ImagesCreateParameters(),
                    new AuthConfig(),
                    new Progress<JSONMessage>());

        }
```

I want to do the equivalent of `docker build -t yyyy -f ./zzzzzz/Dockerfile .` using the Docker.DotNet api but I can't work out a way to do it. Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker build command effectively creates a Tar of the entire working directory and sends it to the build daemon. So much so that if you run `docker build -` it will expect a tar stream from stdin.

You could do something like this to tar up the build directory and pass it to `BuildImageFromDockerFileAsync`: https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/issues/309#issuecomment-547316442

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes I came across that link. I think I just read it and thought that seems like a lot of work and skipped it. Will give it a go. Thanks again.

Comment: After doing more research https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ImageBuild is also handy